# How do I return only the most recent rows in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with job applications from candidates, some candidates submit multiple applications and my goal is to reduce the data set down to only the most recent application from each candidate.

My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'application_date' : ["9/11/2020 10:30:31", "9/11/2020 11:07:59", "9/11/2020 11:09:02", "9/14/2020 13:14:31", "9/14/2020 13:15:15"],
        'candidate_id' : ["001", "002", "002", "002", "002"]
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['application_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['application_date'])

df['rank_application'] = df.groupby('candidate_id')['application_date'].rank(method='first')
```

This returns the following:

```
     application_date candidate_id  rank_application
0 2020-09-11 10:30:31          001               1.0
1 2020-09-11 11:07:59          002               1.0
2 2020-09-11 11:09:02          002               2.0
3 2020-09-14 13:14:31          002               3.0
4 2020-09-14 13:15:15          002               4.0
```

This is where I am stuck. From here I do not know how to only reduce the df to only the most recent per candidate_id. I was originally hoping to order descending and then figure out how to take the rows where rank_application = 1 (but I can't figure it out)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you need:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'application_date' : ["9/11/2020 10:30:31", "9/11/2020 11:07:59", "9/11/2020 11:09:02", "9/14/2020 13:14:31", "9/14/2020 13:15:15"],
        'candidate_id' : ["001", "002", "002", "002", "002"]
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['application_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['application_date'], infer_datetime_format=True)

result = df.iloc[df.groupby('candidate_id')['application_date'].agg(pd.Series.idxmax)]

print(result)
```

Result:

```
     application_date candidate_id
0 2020-09-11 10:30:31          001
4 2020-09-14 13:15:15          002
```

`.iloc[]` takes a series of indices to get the appropriate rows. The `pd.to_datetime` statement may be needed to force the `application_date` to be a suitable datetime format for `pd.Series.idxmax` to work.

Comment: Thank you

When I tried to implement this with a data set provided to me, a problem came up that I cannot resolve. The data was a CSV file from a Google sheet. The data was a little different than my example, so I am now wanting to take the most recent survey submission tied to an application_id.

I used some functions to remove rows with null data

Now I am getting the following errors: IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds and IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds

I am assuming that something happened with indices when I was removing rows with nulls.

Comment: I think you should reset the index after when you remove rows. You can use the reset_index() in pandas

Comment: I'd recommend writing a bit of example code and posting that with a new question - I think you'll get an answer, but it's a problem that's really different from this one, so it deserves its own question.

Answer (score 1):

First, because this is sorting and select in the time data, you should convert your column to pandas date_time to be well operated on pandas by `pd.to_datetime`.

Then you can select the ['application_date'] by choosing the maximum value in the series of time by `df['application_date'].agg(pd.Series.idxmax)`. However, because you are looking for the latest time in different id or rank, you need to add a `groupby` to help the maximum selection for each id.

```
df.groupby('candidate_id')['application_date'].agg(pd.Series.idxmax)
```

If you want to select the application date: you can easily index them by `iloc`

```
df.iloc[df.groupby('candidate_id')['application_date'].agg(pd.Series.idxmax)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a little late with this answer. I happened to stumble upon this post while I was searching for something similar.

This is what I usually do when I am trying to find the most recent record.

```
df['rank_application'] = df.groupby('candidate_id')['application_date'].rank(method='first', ascending=False)
df = df[df.rank_application == 1]
```

The initial approach posted in the question is what I follow.